# Calling external dll after delphi upgrade

Tags: delphi

I have upgraded my Delphi 2007 application to Delphi Seattle. In Delphi 2007 I had a Fortran DLL which was called from my Delphi application. After upgrade I get an error 'Procedure end point not found'. Please note that there is no change to the Fortran DLL and the dll is in the same path as the application exe

The call code from Delphi is

```
type
  TArrayOfTypeNos= array [1..1000] of Integer;
....
procedure CallFunc(
  Idx : Integer; 
  var Nos : Integer;
  var ProductTypes : TArrayOfTypeNos
); stdcall; external 'MyFortranDLL.dll' name '_ThisIsFuncNameinFortran';
```

Can someone please give me some idea as to what could be wrong?

The error I get is:

> The procedure entry point _ThisIsFuncNameinFortran could not be located in dynamic link library

Comment: Nothing in the code you present behaves differently in Seattle from how it behaved in 2007.  I don't recognise that error message.  Please can you quote the error message verbatim, and include a [mcve].

Comment: The error I get is "The procedure entry point _ThisIsFuncNameinFortran could not be located in dynamic link library"

Comment: @MartynA it is loaded implicitly with load time linking, by the loader, because of this: `external 'MyFortranDLL.dll'`

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Thanks, I missed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing has changed between Delphi 2007 and Delphi 10 Seattle that affects the function shown in the question in any way.

The common problems that arise when moving between pre-Unicode Delphi, and Unicode Delphi, relate to differences in the treatment that character and string types. So, `Char` was formerly an alias to `AnsiChar`, but is now an alias to `WideChar`. Likewise for `PChar`, `string` etc. But that's not the case here. The types that you use have identical meaning on all Delphi versions from Delphi 2 upwards.

The error message is:

> The procedure entry point _ThisIsFuncNameinFortran could not be located in dynamic link library.

There is only one way to interpret that error message. The DLL has been located, but it really does not export a function with that name. Check that the actual DLL loaded really is the one that you intended to load. Dependency Walker, or a similar tool, can probably help.

Comment: And if it is only one dll and only one function, he could try to load the dll dynamically (LoadLibrary) and use GetModuleName to check which dll is actually being loaded. Temporarily create an empty dummy implementation of the function and comment the external declaration so the compiler does not complain.

Comment: Dependency Viewer in profile mode has all the info needed to debug this

Answer (score 1):

If the DLL really has not changed, this code should have been failing in D2007 to begin with.  The fact that it works in 2007 but fails in Seattle likely means the same DLL is *not* being loaded.  You can use a tool like [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) or [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to see which DLL is actually being loaded.  And use Embarcadero's [TDUMP](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/TDUMP.EXE,_the_File_Dumping_Utility) utility to see which functions the DLL actually exports.

Answer (score 0):

I encounter the same problems with  Delphi 10.4 using a Microchip dll. The same code & dll works flawlessly with fpc & Lazarus.....

the names of the functions are like Mcp2221_OpenByIndex in the .h file, but in the dll the are _Mcp2221_OpenByIndex with a leading underscore;
The function definition is:

```
function Mcp2221_OpenByIndex(VID: Word; PID: Word; index: Word)     : mcpHandle_; external MCP_DLL; name '_Mcp2221_OpenByIndex';
```

MCP_DLL is a constant containing the name.
When I remove the underscore, this function is not found. If I add underscores to all functions I still get an error for the 2nd function.